# Как прочитать смс с модема подключенного к COM порту

Tags: java, com-port, jssc

Имеется модем подключенный COM порту, я использую библиотеку jssc для работы с ним. Так же подключил COM port sniffer чтобы видеть что происходит на модеме, я отправляю на него команды, так же отправляю команду чтения СМС на сим карте но ответа не получаю не на модеме не в консоли. В чем моя ошибка?

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Modem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1");
        String rn = "\r\n";
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        try {
            port.openPort();
            System.out.println("Открываем порт" + port);
            port.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            System.out.println("Задаем параметры " + port);

            port.writeString("AT+CMGF=1");
            port.writeString(rn);
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            System.out.println("Переводим в режим PDU " + port);

            port.writeString("AT+CPMS=\"MT\"");

            port.writeString(rn);
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            port.writeString("AT+CUSD=1");
            port.writeString(rn);
            port.writeString("*102#");

            Thread.sleep(20000);
            System.out.println("Запрос баланса" + port);


            byte[] s = port.readBytes(8);
            System.out.println("читаем " + s);
            String str = new String(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("читаем буфер " + str);
            String read = port.readString();
            System.out.println("читаем строку " + read);
            port.writeString("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"");
            port.writeString(rn);


            String readSMS = port.readString();
            System.out.println("читаем все смс " + readSMS);
            port.closePort();

            System.out.println("закрываем порт ");



        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Что пишет консоль

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Открываем портjssc.SerialPort@7d6f77cc
Задаем параметры jssc.SerialPort@7d6f77cc
Переводим в режим PDU jssc.SerialPort@7d6f77cc
Запрос балансаjssc.SerialPort@7d6f77cc
читаем [B@5aaa6d82
читаем буфер 
OK


читаем строку +CPMS: 0,20,0,20,0,20

OK

OK

читаем все смс null
закрываем порт 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

как принимаются команды на модеме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разве подобные вещи не должны через JNI делаться ?

Comment: Каким образом может подскажете?

Comment: К сожалению я ничего не знаю об этой технологии, могу лишь сказать что Java в этом плане падает на сверхнизкий уровень и очень неудобна. Могу лишь предложить заводить гугл на всю, с вопросами типа этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121508/how-to-access-usb-ports-in-java

Comment: Вот даже человек ответит в горе комментариев : System.IO.Ports has no USB interfaces, is only for Com Ports. Думаю в переводе не нуждается, не знаю, примите вы это за ответ или нет )